# How ta make a cell OR row selectable for radio button in JSP?

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML table with 2 columns of which 1 column hsa radio buttons. Now to select a radio I have to clikc on the radio button itself. How can i make the radio button select if i click anywhere on the Radio cell () or anywhere on its row ()?

Here is the code:

```
<tr>                     
<TD><INPUT type="radio" name="Radios" value="someValue"></td> 
<TD>someValue</td> 
</tr>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Put your text into this tag:

```
<label for="Radios">someValue</label>
```

You have to add id="radios" into your input tag

Answer (score 0):

Putting a click event handler on the row that calls `click` on its INPUT child element sorta works.  Try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/59p9s/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function handleRadioRow() {
    var t = event.target;
    if (t.tagName.toUpperCase() == "INPUT")
        return;
    while (t.tagName.toUpperCase() != "TR")
        t = t.parentElement;
    var r = t.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
    r.click();
}
</script>

<table>
  <tr onclick="handleRadioRow()" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <TD><INPUT type="radio" name="Radios" value="someValue"></td> 
    <TD>someValue</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="handleRadioRow()" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <TD><INPUT type="radio" name="Radios" value="someValue"></td> 
    <TD>someValue</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```